# Warbler vs SoundModem

Tags: digital-modes, modes, software-defined-radio, satellites

I'm trying to decode a BPSK 1200 (with no success). In this endeavor I tried both [SoundModem](http://uz7.ho.ua/packetradio.htm) and [Warbler](http://members.casema.nl/b.ubbels/Warbler.htm).

The scenario here is the following: Ettus receiver + HDSDR with speaker plugged into mic via an audio cable.

Warbler and SoundModem both do the same job or are there little differences?

Comment: Maybe you can provide some more details.  Where is the signal coming from?  Satellite passes involving doppler effects?  Do you get no decoding at all?  Do you get bad decoding?  In other words, what exactly does "(with no success)" mean?

BPSK 1200 should pretty much be the same in both sound modems.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of unknowns here. Most PSK decoders work virtually the same way. One thing to check is to make sure that your radio is set for Upper Side Band and not any other receive mode.  Other than that we will need more details.